# Stored procedure or trigger to enforce input data

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

My professor is asking me to either use a stored procedure or trigger to ensure that every time a new employee is inserted, the employee has at least one computer assigned, not null.
http://i1294.photobucket.com/albums/b618/uRsh3RRaYm0nD/Capturescreenie_zps67ab757a.jpg
The table layouts are:

**Computer Table**

```
SerialNumber_PK,
Make,
Model
```

**Computer_Employee Table**

```
SerialNumber_PK_FK,
EmployeeNumber_PK_FK,
DateAssigned
```

**Employee Table**

```
EmployeeNumber_PK,
FirstN,
LastN,
Department_FK,
Phone,
Email,
```

I have decided to go with a stored procedure, but I am stuck and I don't know if this is correct.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_AddEmployee
(   @EmployeeNumber Int,
    @FirstName  Char(25),
    @LastName   Char(25),
    @Department Char(35),
    @Phone  Char(12),
    @Email  VarChar(100))
AS
DECLARE @rowcount AS Int

SELECT @rowcount = COUNT(*)
FROM EMPLOYEE AS E
WHERE E.EmployeeNumber = @EmployeeNumber
IF @rowcount > 0
    Begin
        PRINT ' '
        PRINT 'The employee with employee number: '
        PRINT ' '
        PRINT Str(@EmployeeNumber)
        PRINT ' '
        PRINT 'already exists in the EMPLOYEE table.'
        RETURN;
    END;
    
DECLARE @pc_rowcount AS Int
SELECT @pc_rowcount = COUNT(*)
FROM COMPUTER_ASSIGNMENT AS C
WHERE C.EmployeeNumber = @EmployeeNumber
IF @pc_rowcount = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT ' '
        PRINT ' '
        PRINT 'A computer serial number must be assigned to the added employee'
        PRINT 'number in the computer assignment table'
        PRINT ' '
        PRINT ' '
        RETURN;
    END;
IF @pc_rowcount > 0
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE
                (EmployeeNumber, FirstName, LastName, Department, Phone,
                 Email)
        VALUES(@EmployeeNumber, @FirstName, @LastName, @Department, @Phone,
                @Email);
        PRINT '*******************************************************'
        PRINT ' '
        PRINT 'The employee with employee number: '
        PRINT ' '
        PRINT Str(@EmployeeNumber)
        PRINT ' '
        PRINT 'has been added to the EMPLOYEE table.'
        PRINT ' '
        PRINT '*******************************************************'
    END;
```

Comment: stuck how? you need to provide more details about what is confusing you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General rules: Do use `EXISTS` when you want to check for the presence or absence of data, but do not need an explicit `COUNT`.  Don't name stored procedures `sp_MyName`.

**EDIT**: Added transaction for extra credit.

```
create procedure AddEmployee(
  @EmployeeNumber Int,
  @FirstName VarChar(25),
  @LastName VarChar(25),
  @Department VarChar(35),
  @Phone VarChar(12),
  @Email VarChar(100) )
as

  set nocount on

  begin transaction

  if exists ( select 42 from Employee where EmployeeNumber = @EmployeeNumber )
    begin
    rollback transaction
    RaIsError( 'Employee #' + Cast( @EmployeeNumber as VarChar(10) ) + ' already exists.', 13, 0 )
    end

  if not exists ( select 42 from Computer_Assignment where EmployeeNumber = @EmployeeNumber )
    begin
    rollback transaction
    RaIsError( 'Employee #' + Cast( @EmployeeNumber as VarChar(10) ) + ' has no computer.', 13, 1 )
    end

  insert into Employee ( EmployeeNumber, FirstName, LastName, Department, Phone, Email )
    values ( @EmployeeNumber, @FirstName, @LastName, @Department, @Phone,  @Email );

  commit transaction
```

Also don't believe everything you're taught about cascading deletes being a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedure with the use of transactions may save you a good deal of work.

Just start the transaction -> insert employee -> Store last insert ID in some variable -> do a difference between Computer Table serialNumber and Computer_Employee serial number and take the top() of it and store it in a variable -> insert both those variables into computer_Employee table with the current date function

You could do the same thing with triggers, but personally I've never trusted using triggers when getting the insert ID though it has always worked.

Also this assumes your employeeID is auto_Inc

Edit: guess it isn't as you are including it in your param list, so just use that

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info, I am confused by my professor's instructions http://i1294.photobucket.com/albums/b618/uRsh3RRaYm0nD/Capturescreenie_zps67ab757a.jpg